# In Disconnected Network, How can import Updates without WSUS Import server

Tags: wsus

After configuring an upstream WSUS server (WSUSexport server), I transfered the required updates and metadata from the WSUS export server to removable media.

Is there any way to import the updates (Which are exported from WSUSexport server) directly  to a client. here I don't want to use a WSUSimport server.

Answer (score 0):

If you look within your WsusContent directory, you'll see all of the updates divided into folders.  These folders represent the last two chars of the update GUIDs.  Unfortunately, this is how WSUS catalogs all of the update files. So, assuming you know which update corresponds to its particular GUID, you can manually run the updates on the target machines.

Of course, not having a WSUS install precludes you having the ability to scan for needed updates, and you lose the associated update automation.  Since you're halfway there, you should finish the job and create a WSUS server on the disconnected side and import your updates and metabase there.